# Prevent multiple button click

Tags: android

How i can prevent user clic two button on same time.

```
     boolean processClick = true;

        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!processClick) return;

                switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.btn:

                    if (processClick) {
                  //Some action
                 processClick = false;
       }
   }    
}
```

This works fine when action launch a new activity but it's wrong when only show a toast message.

Comment: Show your actual code because you neither launch a new activity nor do you show a toast here.

Comment: Can you add more to the question please, not sure what you are trying to achieve or what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what your problem is. You are implementing OnClickListener for your activity or fragment and overriding the Onclick method but you do not check for the id of the button. this is the code that you should use for your onClick method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.your_first_button_id:
            //your code here
        case R.id.your_second_button_id:
            //your code here
    } 
}
```